How to properly split a snowpark table based on a column value?
I'm just starting out with Snowpark Java API, trying some basic operations.
I have a simple table and I want to split it into multiple tables based on a specific column value, writing to a new table/displaying their content.
The way I managed to do this is:
DataFrame table = session.table("MY_TABLE");

Row[] values = table.select(Functions.col("value")).distinct().collect();

for (Row valuesRow : values) {
  String value = valuesRow.getString(0);
  DataFrame valuesTable = table.filter(Functions.col("value").equal_to(lit(value)));
  valuesTable.show();
}

I'm not sure how efficient this is. I'm running a query to get all the distinct values in the table, followed by a non-parallel iteration through this result, followed by another N queries which scan the initial table.
What would be the proper way to achieve this?
